# How do i use a selected column as a variable for the next selection of the same sub-query

Tags: sql, sql-server

I am trying write a query to create a report and for the report, I need to get the manager of the user who created a form on our system. Because the system is old and changed a lot, there is no easy way to get the manager of the user or get their manager from the time when they created the form. So, the person before me created a function for the job but it is costly. It takes way too long to get a result from the function `fn_getUserMan`. I want to call the function once and then use the result on my other selections as a variable and because it is dependent on `Frm`, I cannot take it out of the sub-query and have it on the main query and set it on a local variable and sql wont let me set the variable on the sub-query.

So my question is this: Is it possible to use `FnMAN` in my next selection as i tried in the query. It says `Invalid column name 'FnMAN'.` when i try it like in the query.

In the code block, it seems like i need it only twice but i actually need it a lot more. I need to check the result and if its some person A, i need to make it some person B like i did with John and Jane. So i really need to make this faster.

```
select *,(--More selection--) 
from
(select
--
--Some selection of 10s of columns
--
(select dbo.fn_getUserMAN((
    select M.txtPerson from Frm (nolock) Fm
    JOIN FLOWDOCUMENTS(nolock) FD ON Fm.ID = FD.FILEPROFILEID
    JOIN FLOWREQUESTS(nolock) FR on FD.PROCESSID = FR.PROCESSID
    JOIN MdlFrm (nolock) M on M.ID = FR.EVENTFORMID
    where FR.EVENTFORMID !=-1 and F.FrmNo = Fm.FrmNo))
) AS 'FnMAN',

(SELECT TOP 1 (
    CASE WHEN      
        (select txtPerson from Frm_Info (nolock) as BB
        inner join FLOWREQUESTS(nolock) FQ on BB.ID = FQ.EVENTFORMID
        and FQ.PROCESSID = FD.PROCESSID) is not null 
        or 
        (select txtPerson from Frm_Info (nolock) as BB
        inner join FLOWREQUESTS(nolock) FQ on BB.ID = FQ.EVENTFORMID
        and FQ.PROCESSID = FD.PROCESSID) !=''
    THEN            
        CASE WHEN FnMAN = 'John Doe'
        THEN 'Jane Doe'
        --More checks and switches on managers
        ELSE FnMAN END     
    WHEN F.txtManager IS NOT NULL THEN F.txtManager END))

from Frm (NOLOCK)  F
INNER JOIN FLOWDOCUMENTS(NOLOCK) FD ON FD.FILEPROFILEID = F.ID 
INNER JOIN LIVEFLOWS(NOLOCK)  LF ON LF.ID = FD.PROCESSID
INNER JOIN FLOWSTATUSES(NOLOCK)  FS ON FS.PROCESS = LF.PROCESS AND FS.VERSION =LF.FLOWVERSION AND FS.STATUS = LF.STATUS
WHERE LF.DELETED = 0  and F.FrmNo IS NOT NULL and F.FrmNo != '') T
```

Comment: What is your DBMS? SQL Server? Is there a good reason why you are using the dangerous `NOLOCK` all over the place? As to the question: You cannot use an alias defined in a select clause in the same select clause. You can solve this with a lateral join (`OUTER APPLY` or `CROSS APPLY`).

Comment: `F` is not defined so your query doesn't make sense.

Comment: @GordonLinoff F is defined, its Frm in the first subquery, check the one above inner joins at the bottom

Comment: @ThorstenKettner There is no reason i have that many `NOLOCK`s other than trying to make the thing run faster. Yes the DB is SQL server. Thanks for your answer, i'll check how i can apply lateral join to this.

Comment: I don't use SQL Server, but from those many people plastering their queries with nolock although this can lead to wrong results, it seems this must be the slowest DBMS on Earth that so many people clutch at that straw!? I have tagged your request with `sql-server` now. Maybe it gets more attention thus.

Comment: @O'Kara . . . You should only use `NOLOCK` when you are willing to get **incorrect** results.  It is slightly faster, but the data may not be accurate.  (The "incorrect" results would typically be approximately accurate.)

Comment: Found a solution with `LEFT JOIN` and posted as an answer. Thanks for all the help guys. Sorry it took a while a while to post the answer, things were a bit busy.  @ThorstenKettner @GordonLinoff

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the solution with `LEFT JOIN` and added a new column to use as a result of `FnMAN`. I dont know whether or not this is a healthy way of having a a solution but it works.

```
select *,(--More selection--) 
from
(select
--
--Some selection of 10s of columns
--       
(SELECT TOP 1 (
    CASE WHEN      
        (select txtPerson from Frm_Info (nolock) as BB
        inner join FLOWREQUESTS(nolock) FQ on BB.ID = FQ.EVENTFORMID
        and FQ.PROCESSID = FD.PROCESSID) is not null 
        or 
        (select txtPerson from Frm_Info (nolock) as BB
        inner join FLOWREQUESTS(nolock) FQ on BB.ID = FQ.EVENTFORMID
        and FQ.PROCESSID = FD.PROCESSID) !=''
    THEN            
        CASE WHEN FnMAN.MAN = 'John Doe'
        THEN 'Jane Doe'
        --More checks and switches on managers
        ELSE FnMAN.MAN END     
    WHEN F.txtManager IS NOT NULL THEN F.txtManager END))

from Frm (NOLOCK)  F
INNER JOIN FLOWDOCUMENTS(NOLOCK) FD ON FD.FILEPROFILEID = F.ID 
INNER JOIN LIVEFLOWS(NOLOCK)  LF ON LF.ID = FD.PROCESSID
INNER JOIN FLOWSTATUSES(NOLOCK)  FS ON FS.PROCESS = LF.PROCESS AND FS.VERSION =LF.FLOWVERSION AND FS.STATUS = LF.STATUS
LEFT JOIN (
(select Fm.FormID, dbo.fn_getUserMAN(M.txtPerson) MAN
    from Frm (nolock) Fm
    JOIN FLOWDOCUMENTS(nolock) FD ON Fm.ID = FD.FILEPROFILEID
    JOIN FLOWREQUESTS(nolock) FR on FD.PROCESSID = FR.PROCESSID
    JOIN MdlFrm (nolock) M on M.ID = FR.EVENTFORMID
    where FR.EVENTFORMID !=-1)
) AS 'FnMAN' on Fm.FormID = F.FormID,
WHERE LF.DELETED = 0  and F.FrmNo IS NOT NULL and F.FrmNo != '') T
```